# Retrieve Windows Events programmatically from a remote computer - Windows XP

Tags: c#, c++, windows-xp, wmi, event-log

I need to retrieve Windows Event Logs programmatically from a remote XP system. Any links/resources related to this would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get event the event log/build a watcher using Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI).  Here's an article on building a "watcher".

http://www.siccolo.com/Articles/CodeProject/LogWatcher_RSS_feed/build_log_watcher_rss_feed_using_WMI.html

There are a few caveats to using WMI remotely, but as long as you have the correct permissions on the remote system, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks George. I was thinking something like this: WindowsImpersonationContext and EventLog.GetEventLogs(<remote system name>). What is your opinion?

Comment: That will work, but if your're looking for performance I would stay away from WMI -- it's dreadfully slow compared to the [Win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385780(v=vs.85).aspx).